# How to initialize git submodule when you already have a local copy?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-submodules

I already have a git repo inside another one. Let's say the directory structure is:

```
repo1
  --.git
  --repo2
    --.git
```

How would I be able to tell git I want repo2 to be a submodule? Note that I already have the entire git repo on disk (I tried doing `git submodule add repo2`, but it said `repo URL: 'repo2' must be absolute or begin with ./|../`)

Comment: What if you delete `repo2` and then use `git submodule add <URL for repo2>`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is `git submodule add <URL> repo2`. Essentially, you always want a remote URL to point to (think about how you initialize a git repo: 
`git clone <repo>`. Hence, it shouldn't be different for git submodules